# How does my rule know when eslint is done with all files?

Tags: javascript, eslint, tslint

I'm currently converting my TSLint rule to ESLint. Here is the TSLint version.

```
import * as Lint from 'tslint'
import * as ts from 'typescript'
import en from '../app/src/i18n/en'

// counter to keep track of already process files
// we need this to know when we are done, e.g. at the last file
let rootFileCount = -1

// temporary storage for all keys that are used in our components
const foundKeys = new Set()

export class Rule extends Lint.Rules.TypedRule {
  public static FAILURE_STRING =
    'could not find i18n key in english language file'

  public applyWithProgram(
    sourceFile: ts.SourceFile,
    program: ts.Program
  ): Lint.RuleFailure[] {
    // at start set the counter to the number of files
    if (rootFileCount === -1) {
      rootFileCount = program.getRootFileNames().length - 1
    } else {
      // decrease counter for every file visited
      rootFileCount -= 1
    }

    const failures = this.applyWithFunction(sourceFile, walk)

    // when done with files check if we have unused keys inside our translation files
    if (rootFileCount === 0) {
      Object.keys(en).forEach(key => {
        if (!foundKeys.has(key)) {
          throw new Error(`i18n key "${key}" is not being used in any file`)
        }
      })
    }

    return failures
  }
}

function walk(ctx: Lint.WalkContext<void>): void {
  return ts.forEachChild(ctx.sourceFile, function cb(node: ts.Node): void {
    if (node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.CallExpression) {
      const callExpression = node as ts.CallExpression
      if (callExpression.expression.getText() === 'i18n.transl') {
        const arg = callExpression.arguments[0]
        const argumentName = (arg as ts.Identifier).text
        if (!en[argumentName]) {
          ctx.addFailureAtNode(node, Rule.FAILURE_STRING)
        }
        foundKeys.add(argumentName)
      }
    }
    return ts.forEachChild(node, cb)
  })
}
```

What does it do?
It goes through all my files and looks for `i18n.transl('foo')`. We use language files which look like this:

```
// en.js
module.exports = {
  foo: 'foo in english'
}

// de.js
module.exports = {
  foo: 'foo in german'
}
```

The rule should find keys inside our language files that we never use in our app. Let's say our language files look like this

```
// en.js
module.exports = {
  foo: 'foo in english',
  bar: 'bar in english'
}

// de.js
module.exports = {
  foo: 'foo in german',
  bar: 'bar in german'
}
```

But `i18n.transl('bar')` is never used.

My problem is: How do I know when ESLint is done with all my files? This would be the chance to compare the real language files with all occurrences found in the app. In TSLint I used `program.getRootFileNames().length` to get the total number of files which are being processed. Then I simply counted down and at `0` I compared the language file `en` with my temporary Set `foundKeys`.

I know about the `Program` and `Program:exit` hooks but they are only per file. I need hooks for something `ESLint:start` and `ESLint:done`.

I also looked at all the existing rules but couldn't find any hints. They all work on single files and not with multiple files.

Any ideas? I'm stuck. Thank you!

Comment: Any luck ? I seem to have stumbled upon the same issue and found this